# Vert.X HttpServer timeouts under load

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx-verticle

I'm using the basic vert.x example verticle running an HTTP server;

```
package io.vertx.starter;

import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;

public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

  @Override
  public void start() {
    vertx.createHttpServer()
        .requestHandler(req -> req.response().end("Hello Vert.x!"))
        .listen(8080);
  }
}
```

This starts up and responds, so I thought I'd give it a quick load test via `ab -n 100000 -c 50 http://localhost:8080`

Every run is relatively consistent, it times out right around 16,400 completed requests, give or take 10. I've tried playing with `setWorkerPoolSize` and `setEventLoopPoolSize` on the vertx options, but nothing seems to have an effect.

I also tried scaling the verticle via `--instances 10` and confirmed it does deploy 10 verticles. Oddly, the same 16,400 is where it dies.

The logs show no errors or warnings, it just seems to die under load. If I hit it with a browser a few seconds later, it responds happily again. Has anyone come across this? I'm curious why this happens, and how I might fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out vertx is just fine.. `ab` has a bug of some sort. Tested with jmeter and saw exactly what I'd expect.